# sanitizing unsafe URL value javascript

Tags: angular, html-sanitizing

Angular 2 final release.

I have my link as following with refers to the href="javascript:;" 
 my link

and i am getting following warning

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value javascript:; (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

I need my link to be javascript:; because if i make it '#' or '' it refreshes the page.

I have read couple of posts where people report this issue to angular folks and they will fix it.. any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the purpose of having a link with dummy href in your case? Most likely you have XY problem with `javascript:;`.

Comment: ng-bootstrap dropdown main href we gotta keep it empty and have its drop down items. if we don't keep it javascripot:; and click it refreshes itself.

Comment: i am generating elements dynamically. they can have direct links or drop downs. if they link i use url to populate in href. if they drop down i make href as void(0); so clicking on it should not refresh the page.

Comment: You can have <a> without href or have <a href=...> with preventDefault() or have any other inline element with click event. So yes, this is likely XY problem, and you're trying to solve it the hard way. Please, provide the details for the underlying problem in the question.

Comment: got it i will try to use alternate element

Comment: Have you tried to use DomSanitizer?

Comment: solved pls check my ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

done with the help of pkozlowski-opensource

I don't think you want to trick sanitization here. If you are using a link that has a click event and it shouldn't trigger navigation just prevent default action on the event, ex.:

```
<a (click)="$event.preventDefault(); doSth()"> or even shorter
<a (click)="!!doSth()">
```

reference post 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11805#issuecomment-248840338

i simply removed href and added a click event like as following

```
<a (click)="!!navigateToUrl(urlVar)">..</a>
```

Note: '!!' prevent triggering 'href' action and prevent page refresh. 
navigateToUrl is my js method simply i am doing as

```
if(urlVar){
window.location.href=urlVar
}
```

works like charm no warnings etc..